Prisma schema with Supabase database - I want to have only necessary models in schema
So, i am creating a nextjs app using Prisma ORM and Supabase PostgreSQL database with SupabaseAuth. I have a question about prisma schema. Ive been fighting with chatgpt with this issue but it just wasted my time and I did not get any answer. So here is my issue: after running 'npx prisma db pull', my prisma schema was full with all the tables from my database, including models such as audit_log_entries, flow_state or mfa_amr_claims etc, which are "supabase managed tables". I wanted to then delete all the unnecessary stuff like this in the schema, and just leave my Todo table (created by me) and users table, so its clear and I have only the models i need for my app. So after countless hours of trying to do it and fighting with chatgpts help, here is my base question (as he cant answer that either and just gives me answers which in the end are the same over and over) - is it even possible? Maybe I am just bothering with something that is impossible, and the idea is just false. Thanks for any answers.

I usually create TypeScript interfaces extending the Prisma models, Making it more readable and customized, having it in only one folder.
/interfaces/User.ts
import { User } from "@prisma/client"


// Omits User createdAt, updatedAt and password from Prisma model, and you can override it as needed

export default interface UserInterface extends <Omit<User, "createdAt" | "updatedAt" | "password"> {
     password?: string // make password optional
     someNewAttr: string
}

